# How to Create Delay in JavaFX

Tags: java, algorithm, javafx, delay, simulation

we're tasked to simulate Prim's algorithm in JavaFX.
The idea is, to highlight each step of the algorithm and have a delay of at least 300 milliseconds.
So I created these functions.

The first function repaints the AnchorPane such that it removes all components then adds everything relevant to it.

```
private void repaintGraphViewTab() {
    graphPane.getChildren().clear();
    for(int counter = 0; counter < temporaryLines.size(); counter++) {
        Double sourceXPos = temporaryLines.get(counter).getSource().getXPosition();
        Double sourceYPos = temporaryLines.get(counter).getSource().getYPosition();
        Double destXPos = temporaryLines.get(counter).getDestination().getXPosition();
        Double destYPos = temporaryLines.get(counter).getDestination().getYPosition();
        Line currentLine = new Line(sourceXPos, sourceYPos, destXPos, destYPos);
        currentLine.setSmooth(true);
        currentLine.setDisable(true);
        currentLine.setStrokeWidth(1);
        currentLine.setStroke(simulatedColor);
        graphPane.getChildren().add(currentLine);
    }
    for(int counter = 0; counter < temporaryPoints.size(); counter ++) {
        Circle currentPoint = new Circle(temporaryPoints.get(counter).getXPosition(),temporaryPoints.get(counter).getYPosition(),5);
        currentPoint.setFill(simulatedColor);
        currentPoint.setSmooth(true);
        currentPoint.setDisable(true);
        graphPane.getChildren().add(currentPoint);  
    }
}
```

The second function modifies the ArrayList I created that would store temporary vertices and edges that I would use in repainting the anchorpane. Since the code for the prims simulation is long. I'll just show an example.

```
//After sorting the current edges traversable by ascending weight.
Edge currentLowestWeightEdge = adjacentEdges.remove(0);
temporaryLines.add(currentLowestWeightEdge);
repaintGraphViewTab();
Thread.sleep(300);
//Where this is called every time there is a need to be changed with the temporary lines or points arraylist.
```

After using such, the delay works fine. But the scene doesn't update until after the whole simulatePrims function has been finished. What am I doing wrong? Please help and advice thank you.

Comment: Thread.sleep() pauses the UI thread. You should look at the Timeline class and API to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task

Comment: Yes, finally got it to work. Thank you all for the help.